# Using DecimalFormat inside parallel stream

Tags: java, multithreading, java-stream, thread-safety

I have read that DecimalFormat is not thread safe. I wanted to check the correct way of using it inside parallelStream. See my sample code:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

public class ThreadTest {
    private final static DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
    private static final ThreadLocal<DecimalFormat> FORMATTER =
            new ThreadLocal<DecimalFormat>() {
                @Override
                protected DecimalFormat initialValue() {
                    return new DecimalFormat("#.##");
                }
            };

    @Test
    public void test() {

        List<Double> numberList = new ArrayList<>();
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i=0;i<1000;++i) {
            numberList.add(r.nextDouble() * 100);
        }
       

        double sum = 0.0;
        for(int i=0;i<1000;++i) {
            sum = sum + Double.parseDouble(df.format(numberList.get(i)));
        }
        System.out.println(sum);

        AtomicReference<Double> sum6 = new AtomicReference<>(0.0);
        numberList.stream().parallel().forEach(aDouble -> {
            double val = Double.parseDouble(FORMATTER.get().format(aDouble));
            sum6.set(sum6.get() + val);
        });
        System.out.println(sum6);

    }
}
```

In the above test case, output of `sum` and `sum6` is coming out to be different even though the `sum6` is using `ThreadLocal` instance.

Can anyone help me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This code is not threadsafe: `sum6.set(sum6.get() + val);`  two threads can call set with different values of get and val so one will trample on the results of the other thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use `AtomicReference`, don't use its `set` method like DuncG already said. Instead use its `accumulateAndGet` or `getAndAccumulate` method (since you don't care about the result it doesn't matter which one):

```java
sum6.accumulateAndGet(val, (x, y) -> x + y);
```

Slightly better is to use `DoubleAdder` instead, as it has a simple `add` method.

The best solution however is to not update any intermediate object yourself, and let the stream collect / reduce for you:

```java
double sum6 = numberList.stream()
        .parallel()
        .mapToDouble(aDouble -> Double.parseDouble(FORMATTER.get().format(aDouble)))
        .sum();
```

Comment: It must be emphasized that this rounding approach will break if the default locale does not use a dot as decimal separator. Using `Math.round(aDouble*100)*0.01` will not depend on the environment, is simpler, more efficient, and eliminates the need for maintaining a `ThreadLocal` of formatters. And, by the way, `stream().parallel()` can be simplified to `.parallelStream()`.

Answer (score 3):

You have unsafe code when incrementing `sum6.set(sum6.get() + val);`, you could try replacing with `DoubleAdder`:

```
DoubleAdder sum6 = new DoubleAdder();
numberList.stream().parallel().forEach(aDouble -> {
    double val = Double.parseDouble(FORMATTER.get().format(aDouble));
    sum6.add(val);
});
System.out.println(sum6);
```

Also, `FORMATTER` is more concise and avoids anonymous class declaration if you simply use `ThreadLocal.withInitial`:

```
private static final ThreadLocal<DecimalFormat> FORMATTER =ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> new DecimalFormat("#.##"));
```

Comment: The answer by Rob Spoor using `sum()` is tidier than using `DoubleAdder` / `AtomicReference`.